# Adding background color for transparent images for wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a transparent images with a shape in the middle, in which i want the transparent areas to be black(or other). Is there any way to do this dynamically? It will be very helpful if any samples available. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest the image in a content control and set its background. 
For instance:

```
<Grid Background="Black"> 
    <Image .../>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Very simple way, thanks. If possible, can we save this `Grid` as a single image?

Comment: You can save it as a user control, although the plumbing you need in order to get it to work does not worth the overhead for such a small piece of UI